# how to fix useEffect has a missing dependency "Dispatch"

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a problem with my eslint and I'm not sure how to respond with my dispatch's:

```
 const { messages } = ChatReducer;
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);
  console.log(isTyping)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (messages[messages.length - 1].type === 'bot') {
      setIsTyping(true);
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsTyping(false);
        dispatch(wait_end());
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [messages]);

  useEffect(() => 
  dispatch(answer_Message(['hi ','hi two'])
  ), []);
return (
  <>
{messages.map((message, index) => (
          <>
            {message.text ? (
              <Styled.MessageFlexColumn ref={messagesEndRef} key={index}>
                {message.type === 'user' ? (
                  <UserText key={index}>{message.text}</UserText>
                ) : (
                  <BotText
                    key={index}
                    isTyping={isTyping && index === messages.length - 1}
                  >
                    {message.text}
                  </BotText>
                )}
                <Styled.Status />
              </Styled.MessageFlexColumn>
            ) : (
              ''
            )}
            <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
          </>
        ))}
  </>
)
```

**action:**

```
export const checkMessage = text => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(sendMessage(text));
    dispatch(wait_anwser());
    dispatch(botMessage(verify(text)));
  };
};

export const answer_Message = text => {
  return dispatch => {
    text.map((message, index) => {
      dispatch(botMessage(message));
    })
  }
}
```

Well I also have a problem with my useEffect and my state
I'm basically using it to send an array of initial messages to display in my chat:

```
  useEffect(() => 
  dispatch(answer_Message(['hi ','hi two'])
  ), []);
```

The problem is that when sending 2 texts
and my isTyping state is true only once
even being 2 texts and not enter on my if:

> if (messages[messages.length - 1].type === 'bot'

alert eslint:

```
Line 70:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
  Line 74:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

Comment: By adding `dispatch` as a depedency like the error says?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to dispatch that as your function dispatches as well, or you could try adding the dispatch as a dependency inside the `[dispatch]`

Comment: no need  this:   useEffect(() => 
  dispatch(answer_Message(['hi ','hi two'])
  ), []);?

Comment: u can help me about second problem? first useEffect / state

Comment: if i send two messages : useEffect(() => {
    if (messages[messages.length - 1].type === 'bot') {
      setIsTyping(true);
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsTyping(false);
        dispatch(wait_end());
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [messages]); in second time dont enter on my if